# Unable to modify String variable through method in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, immutability

I am currently learning Java, but am having issues understanding how to use a method to modify the object a string variable points towards.

I am working on making a code to return the bigger and smaller number of an array and to notify if there're any duplicates. This could be easily achievable with an if/else, I am aware, but that won't help me learn much, as the only thing that allows it is the small size of the array list of the exercise.

The code inside the GestionarNumeros() method works perfectly fine if I use it inside the main class, but won't work if I create a method with it and then execute it. I know that `string`s are immutable, but I am unsure of how to or if it's even possible to make the code work with a method. I'd appreciate any help or pointing towards the place where the information I need could be found.

I'll leave my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
    String res = "";
        
    añadirNumeros(sc,numeros);
    Collections.sort(numeros);
    GestionarNumeros(numeros,res);
    System.out.println(res);
        
    }

    public static void añadirNumeros (Scanner sc, ArrayList<Integer> numeros) {
        while (numeros.size() < 3) {
        System.out.println("Introduzca número:");
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        numeros.add(num);
            }
        }
    public static void GestionarNumeros (ArrayList<Integer> numeros, String res) {
        res = "El número más pequeño es el " + numeros.get(0) + "."
            + "\nEl número más grande es el " + numeros.get(2) + "."
            + "\nDuplicados: ";
        for(int a = 0; a < numeros.size(); a++) {  
            for(int b = a + 1; b < numeros.size(); b++) {  
                if(numeros.get(a) == numeros.get(b)) {  
                   res = res + " " + numeros.get(b) + ".";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Return `res` from the method instead.